# Issue with parallel testing in pytest

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, pytest

So I have two test cases in a map. From command prompt I type "pytest -n 2" then hit Enter. Instead of opening two browsers and execute them in parallel, pytest is opening 4 browsers, but only two of them are executing the test cases.
And if I add one more test case to that map, and execute "pytest -n 3" from command prompt, pytest is opening 9 browser, from which only 3 are executing the test cases. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share part of the code of your test so people can have a clearer view of where the problem could be?

Comment: Hi. I solved the issue with pytest-parallel. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @rodut Could you convert your comment into answer and explain how pytest-parallel solved you issue?

Comment: Sure. I was just starting to study automation so initially I had two "driver = webdriver.Chrome()", one in the  setUp method, and one in tearDown method. I solved this simple, by declaring it only in main class. If I can help you any further, just let me know.